# What is the difference between, service reload and service restart?

Tags: linux

What the difference between services [name] reload and service [name] restart?
actually, they same..
well, what recommand to use?

Answer (score 43):

Some services which support the `reload` command can reload their configuration without fully shutting down and starting up again.  Postfix does this, as does Apache.  It is very useful if you need to make configuration changes to a live server without incurring even a few seconds of downtime.

Comment: hello just wondering, how can i tell if a specific system support reloading ?

Comment: @sbabtizied Assuming you are using a modern Linux with Systemd, you can check the service unit file in `/usr/lib/systemd/system/*.service` to see if it has an `ExecReload` defined that is different from `ExecRestart`. There's probably an easier way but off the top of my head I do not know it.

Answer (score 16):

Reload will tell the service to reload its configuration files, but keep the same process running.  Restart tells it to shut down entirely, then restart.

Answer (score 8):

Generally speaking, `restart` will terminate the service in question and restart it; `reload` will only reload the configuration file.

Since `reload` only reloads the config, it will cause less disruption to existing activities and currently open connections; users might not even notice that it was run. However, depending on what server we're talking about, some options may not be changeable using `reload`; and if the server is using too much memory, etc, it may be necessary to use `restart` to force it to start from a clean slate.

Further, note that not all services support `reload`; all services support `restart`.

Comment: e.g. mariadb doesn't support `reload`.

Answer (score 1):

`restart` shuts the service down and then starts it up again, whereas `reload` instructs the daemon to reload its configuration. You use whichever is appropriate for your situation.